# Avoid external display to show native iOS screen when app entering background

Tags: ios, swift, ios-background-mode, external-display

My app has an external display when a second screen is connected. It displays the main content I want that people see while I navigate through others views. it works fine.

Is there a way to keep this external display active when app is entering background ?

I enabled background mode in Capabilities tab, I'm able to run code in background, it refreshes correctly when I enter foreground again.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the answer is No.

As soon as your app goes to the background, it loses control of the external screen.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is what I was thinking... impossible to switch from my app to another app and keeping alive its external display...